# How to stop this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, event-handling, jtextfield

I'm trying validate my jtextfeild to enter only money value. which include only numeric and a full-stop. ex-17652.50 

So I tried this method. But while it is executing I got this **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1**

Here is the method.

```
    private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    try {
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        String mny[] = jTextField1.getText().split("\\.");
        if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK) || (c == '.'))) {
            getToolkit().beep();
            evt.consume();
        }
        if (mny[1].length() == 2) {
            getToolkit().beep();
            evt.consume();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting Array Index Out of Bounds Exception after I typed the first number in textfeild. As I understand this is happening because mny[o] should occur after I enter fullstop. But I can't find a solution. Please help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iy there is no dot in you input `String mny[] = jTextField1.getText().split("\\.");` will return an array with only one item. Arrays in java are zero based. So `mny[1].length()` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should check here if your array have a size of 2

```
if (mny.length > 1 && mny[1].length() == 2) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your condition to :

```
    if (mny.length > 1 && mny[1].length() == 2) {
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
```

(or something similar, depending on the required logic)

Comment: yeah working.. Thank you so much.. I tried (mny[0].length > 1 && mny[1].length() == 2) but never thought this one.. :D :D thank you...